# Como contar o total de Caracteres de um arquivo txt, incluindo espaços e '\n'?

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *arquivoRead; 
    FILE *arquivoEscrita; 
    char ch; 
    int count=0;
    int lin, col;


    arquivoRead = fopen(argv[3], "r"); 

    if(arquivoRead == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro na abertura do arquivo\n");
    }

    if(argc < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Quantidade insuficiente de parâmetros\n");
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0 ) {

    }


    arquivoEscrita = fopen("arquivoEscrita.txt", "w");

    while( (ch=fgetc(arquivoRead) ) != EOF ){

        fprintf(arquivoEscrita, "%c", ch);
        fprintf(stdout, "%c", ch);

      count++;

    }

    char matriz[count][count];

    while( (ch=fgetc(arquivoRead) ) != EOF ){
        for(lin=0; lin<count; lin++){
            for(col=0; col<count; col++){
                matriz[lin][col] = ch;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for(lin=0; lin<count; lin++){
        for(col=0; col<count; col++){
            fprintf(stdout, "%c ", matriz[lin][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



    fclose(arquivoRead);

    fclose(arquivoEscrita);

    return 0;
}
```

Estou tentando colocar todos esses caracteres em uma matriz de char, mas preciso saber o total de caracteres. O valor do contador ou fica com 0 ou com um valor estranho, além disso, a matriz só está armazenando valores lixo da memória.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse site: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa carregar o conteúdo de um arquivo para a memória para calcular o seu tamanho total, isso se torna imprático nos casos no qual o tamanho do arquivo execede o tamanho da memória disponível.

Calculando o tamanho (em bytes) de um arquivo na linguagem C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    FILE * fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    fseek( fp, 0L, SEEK_END );
    long tam = ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Tamanho total do arquivo: %ld bytes\n", tam );
    return 0;
}
```

Calculando o tamanho (em bytes) de um arquivo em C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    std::ifstream in( argv[1], std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary );
    long tam = in.tellg();
    std::cout << "Tamanho total do arquivo: " << tam << " bytes" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```